# Publishing free application to Android market, but in-app billing in future

Tags: android, google-play

I want to launch an application to Android market. It will be free. But in the future I'm planning to add more features and these features can be used with in app billing.

Regarding to Android checklist, in Google Play a free application can't be changed to paid application. http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#free-priced

But what about in app billing. Any user freely can install my application but will pay if he/she wants more features.

What should I do while launching application ? Is it OK to select free as app type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always add in-app billing into a free application, what they mean when they say you cannot change a free application to paid is you cannot change a free app to an app that you have to pay to download

Comment: Thank you. But it seems like my country is not suitable to create a Google merchant account. I hope I can create one in future and I can add in-app billing features.