# Prepare android application for future in app billing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I want to release an android application that for the moment will be completely free, but in the future might have some in app products. As I understood, once the app is published you cannot switch from free to billing. Is it enough if I add now the permission in the manifest for BILLING, or it should also be implemented?

According to an old question on this subject, (I would need updated information: [Publishing free application to Android market, but in-app billing in future](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20127970/1592546)), paid application does not refer to in app products, and in app billing can be added later. Is this still true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still the same policy, what they mean by "you cannot change from free to paid app" is that you can't start charging people for the download of the application later, since it would make conflict with the already existing downloads. It's ok to publish it as free and just add billing inside the app with the new update, when you finish that part of the app.

Comment: Could you provide some link to documentation? Or have you tested this?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en the only documentation you need, you can even see that the Paid Apps and In-App items are separate things. I work with a lot of people who do this regulary, since you can't usually just add in-app purchase (you can, but what's the point) when your app doesn't even have downloads.
"Once your app has been offered for Free, the app can't be changed to Paid. If you want to charge for the app, you need to create a new app with a new package name and set a price." <- states if you want to charge for APP, not in-app